# NCSolve - solve for a variable

Tags: equation-solving, ncalgebra

I use the latest NCAlgebra package (5.0) for non-commutative algebra.

```
<< NC` 
<< NCAlgebra`
NCSolve[a**x==b,x]
```

How do I solve for the variable x, assuming there is an inverse for a? Somehow this code does not output any solution. Can you help?

Answer (score 6):

I found the NCGBX methods (Gröbner Basis). This problem is easily solved in the following way:

```
<<NC`
<<NCAlgebra`
<<NCGBX`
SetKnowns[a,b,inv[a]]
SetUnknowns[x]
NCMakeGB[{a**x==b},10]
```

This returns:

```
{x -> a^-1 ** b}
```

as expected. I had to include the inverse $a^{-1}$ into the SetKnowns list. (Commutative or non-commutative) Algebras assume a ring structure among its definition properties, which does not include the existence of multiplicative inverses, in its most general case.

Comment: Please, try << NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
<< NCGBX`
SetKnowns[A, B, b, inv[B], inv[A]]
SetUnknowns[x]
NCMakeGB[{A ** x + B ** x == b}, 20]